# Meaning? "One of a kind. Top of the line. A real doggone keeper"

Tags: american-english, slang, quotes, cinema

> One of a kind. Top of the line. A real doggone keeper

This a phrase spoken by Walter to Chris in the movie "Get Out". YouTube [link](https://youtu.be/Ulua0UQJCas?t=48s)

I think I can understand the first two phrases...

"One of a kind, top of the line" means the best female among all other females.

Okay, but what does "A real doggone keeper" mean?

A girl can keep a boy? Control a boy? Attracting the mind of a boy? so that the boy will never betray her?

Is that what it means?

Comment: A fish that is long enough is a "keeper".  The fisherman must throw back fish that are less than the prescribed length for the species of fish.

Comment: "One of a kind" and "top of the line" are simply advertising phrases (as it "a real keeper"), used to identify something that is supposedly superior.

Comment: "The best female within the female"?

Comment: @user1284969632635 em.. yupe.. I think it should be "The best female among all females".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Doggone](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/doggone)

> attributive
>
> Used to express feelings of annoyance, surprise, or
>   pleasure. ‘now just a doggone minute’. *- OLD*

Given the context of "One of a kind. Top of the line", the feeling being expressed here is pleasure.

The word keeper is being used informally:

[Keeper](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/keeper)

> informal
>
> Someone with good qualities, who you can have a long relationship with.
>   *- Cambridge*

*A real doggone keeper* means someone that has truly great qualities, someone who the speaker would like to have a long relationship with.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that "doggone" is usually used as a non-profane substitute for "god damn."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a "keeper" is normally a boyfriend or girlfriend that is worthy of marriage and to hold onto them, or "keep" them for the long term. It's not sexist, in that both genders use the term about love interests. In fact, I've mostly heard it from women speaking about boyfriends.

"doggone" of course, in this context, means "genuine".

Having just seen that film on DVD, it is an extraordinary exchange because the hired help, Walter speaks the lines to the family guest, Chris, and in polite circles, it would be considered forward, if not inappropriate. And there's also the creepy smile while saying it. But it's borderline between acceptable and not. It's a compliment to Chris's girlfriend by someone who has worked with and knows the family and the daughter/girlfriend for a long time. Just one of the many borderline inappropriate moments that make that film such a hit.